# Unique PHP path in request URI

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress' wp-config.php file, the default language is set by:

```
define('WPLANG', '');
```

However, I need just one specific plugin's page to be in Chinese, and not in English.

The path is: http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=tbs-menu

I replaced the code above with the new one

```
if (basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)) == 'admin.php'){
    define( 'WPLANG',  'zh_CN');
} else {
    define( 'WPLANG',  'en_US');
}
```

This however changes the whole admin section to Chinese (due to the admin section falling under admin.php as well).

I have tried a few path combinations with no luck.  == 'admin.php?page=tbs-menu'  does not work either, neither does == 'tbs-menu'

Is there any way to just have that one Plugin page work with the REQUEST_URI format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just use `strpos`

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'tbs-menu') !== false) {
    define( 'WPLANG',  'zh_CN');
} else {
    define( 'WPLANG',  'en_US');
}
```